# Swift programmatically adding constraints to labels

Tags: swift, constraints, label

I am in a for index loop and adding labels based off each index item. Because I am programmatically adding these labels I don't know how to constrain them to the far right of the device width. I explain below how I think the constraints work.
My goal = trailing space to superview (or containing view) constant set to 8.

```
let y_align = 340 * index + 70
let x_align = self.deviceWidth - 110
var derp = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
derp.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x_align), CGFloat(y_align))    
derp.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right    
derp.text = json["things"][index]["thing"].string!    
self.some_view_container.addSubview(derp)

//now this is what I understand about constraints    
let xconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(    
    item: derp, //-- the object that we want to constrain    
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain    
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object    
    toItem: some_view_container, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to    
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, //-- the attribute of the different object    
    multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier    
    constant: 8 //-- regular constant    
)

derp.addConstraint(xconstraint)
```

this is what I want in human terms

- item:        I want to constrain the derp which is the value of the json
- attribute:   I want to constrain the trailing space of it so it pushes it all the way to the right
- relatedBy:   no idea here, I don't care if it is related to anything, because I just want the trailing space to the superview
- toItem:      I want to push it to the right of the superview OR it's container which is some_view_container
- attribute:   no idea here, I don't care about the attribute of the view container
- multiplier:  I just want the number of the constant so multiply by 1
- constant:    I want the trailing space to be 8 away from the edge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code as reference:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addLabels()
 }

 func addLabels(){
    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    //Here recopilate the constranins for later activation
    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    //Here I'm assuming that there are 5 labels
    for index in 0..<5 {
        //adjust this to spaciate labels
        let y_align = CGFloat(20 * index + 70)
        let x_align = deviceWidth - 110
        var derp = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        derp.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x_align), CGFloat(y_align))
        derp.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        derp.text = "things \(index)"

        let xconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: derp, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: self.view, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: -8 //-- (Take a look here, its a minus)
        )
        let yconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: derp, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: self.view, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: y_align //-- regular constant
        )
        //recopilate constraints created here
        constraints.append(xconstraint)
        constraints.append(yconstraint)
        derp.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        //add them to the desired control
        self.view.addSubview(derp)
    }
    //This will tell iOS to use your constraint
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**for swift 3.0**

```
func addLabels(){
    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    //Here recopilate the constranins for later activation
    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    //Here I'm assuming that there are 5 labels
    for index in 0..<5 {
        //adjust this to spaciate labels
        let y_align = CGFloat(20 * index + 70)
        let x_align = deviceWidth - 110
        var derp = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
        derp.center = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(x_align), y:CGFloat(y_align))

        derp.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
        derp.text = "things \(index)"

        let xconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: derp, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: self.view, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: -8 //-- (Take a look here, its a minus)
        )
        let yconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: derp, //-- the object that we want to constrain
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, //-- the attribute of the object we want to constrain
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, //-- how we want to relate THIS object to A DIFF object
            toItem: self.view, //-- this is the different object we want to constrain to
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, //-- the attribute of the different object
            multiplier: 1, //-- multiplier
            constant: y_align //-- regular constant
        )
        //recopilate constraints created here
        constraints.append(xconstraint)
        constraints.append(yconstraint)
        derp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //add them to the desired control
        self.view.addSubview(derp)
    }
    //This will tell iOS to use your constraint
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```